# gulp4 install error on windows7 64bit

Tags: gulp

this git bash run is command

```
npm install -g gulpjs/gulp#4.0 -g
```

install process output error

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /gulp/chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.1

install after

```
gulp -v
[10:53:26] CLI version 1.2.2
[10:53:26] Local version 0.0.1
```

build project error

```
gulp build_dev
[04:44:54] Unsupported gulp version 0.0.1
```

???

Comment: What you quoted is not an error.

Comment: How to solve the above problems?

Comment: why ?  Local version 0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Comment: thank you ,   MyProject / node_module/gulp  is error , Cause the problem
.